# python subprocess.run writes before file.write

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script to collect benchmarking information on some other code. I have some diagnostic info that I am trying to write to a file before I run my benchmarking code, but for some reason the benchmarking output comes before my diagnostics. Here is a sample for what I am trying to do and the results I am getting:

```
f = open(outputFile, 'a+')
f.write("Diagnostic Info")
subprocess.run([benchmark, args...], stdout=f, stderr=f)
f.close()
```

Results:

```
STDOUT Results
STDERR Results
Diagnostic Info
```

For parsing purposes I need the diagnostics info first. I have tried to insert a time.sleep() line between f.write and subprocess but that did not help.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `f.flush()` (or opening `f` in non-buffered mode in the first place), so that `Diagnostic Info` is actually written to disk before your benchmark runs.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the quick response.